# hyphanating of Capital letter consecutively in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to hyphenate  the token with capital letters which is coming consecutively.
For example:

```
Mr. Harry Potter going to school
```

Then output should be:

```
Mr. Harry-Potter going to school.
```

It needs to chunk all token start with capital letters consecutively. 
Except following regex pattern

Like some other example Central Government of sun then it should be Central-Government of sun.

My code is:

```
public class Capitalize {

        static String str="mr. Harry Potter is going to school";
        StringBuffer regex = new StringBuffer("Eco[\\.]|Gr[\\.]|Emp[\\.]|Rs[\\.]|Ms[\\.]|No[\\.]|Nos[\\.]|Dt[\\.]|Sh[\\.]|Mr[\\.]|Mrs[\\.]|Admn[\\.]|Ad[\\.]|Smt[\\.]|GOVT[\\.]|Govt[\\.]|Deptt[\\.]|Tel[\\.]|Secy[\\.]|Estt[\\.]|Asstt[\\.]|Hqrs[\\.]|DY[\\.]|Supdt[\\.]|w[\\.]e[\\.]f[\\.]|&I[\\.]|N[\\.]|[0-9]+[\\.][0-9]+[\\.]");
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        public void show()
        {
        StringTokenizer strtkn=new StringTokenizer(str);
        while (strtkn.hasMoreTokens()) {

            String str1=strtkn.nextToken();

            if(Character.isUpperCase(str1.charAt(0)))
            {
                sb.append(str1+"-");

            }
            sb.append(str1+" ");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Final :" +sb.toString());
        }
```

It is giving this output

```
Final :mr. Harry-Harry Potter-Potter is going to school 
but i want this output
mr. Harry-Potter is going to school
```

And also I want to ignore:

```
 StringBuffer regex = new StringBuffer("Eco[\\.]|Gr[\\.]|Emp[\\.]|Rs[\\.]|Ms[\\.]|No[\\.]|Nos[\\.]|Dt[\\.]|Sh[\\.]|Mr[\\.]|Mrs[\\.]|Admn[\\.]|Ad[\\.]...... values if they come into string.
```

Please suggest some solution of my problem.

Comment: You're missing an `else` statement. Also you need to track the hyphenate or not across consecutive tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, one-line solution for you:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\b[A-Z][a-z]+) (?=[A-Z][a-z]+)", "$1-");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `(?!Sir|Miss)([A-Z][a-z]+) (?!(?:Mrs|Mr|No)\.)([A-Z][a-z]+)`
and replace w/ `$1-$2`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jH7zC4)

- `(?!Sir|Miss)` list of special words to ignore
- `([A-Z][a-z]+)` word starting with upper case letter
- `' '` followed by a space
- `(?!(?:Mrs|Mr|No)\.)` list of special dot-ending words
- `([A-Z][a-z]+)` followed by a word starting with upper case letter

per the modified request in the comment below
`(?!Sir|Miss)([A-Z][a-z]+) (?!(?:Mrs|Mr|No)\.)(?=[A-Z][a-z]+)`
and replace w/ `$1-`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wT7jK7)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple solution.but if in case of like consecutive 3 or 4 or more capital token are come then it should also get hyphenated e.g. Mr. Harry Jerry Merry Potter is going to school then output should be Mr. Harry-Jerry-Merry-Potter is going to school

Comment: @Aditya I edited my solution above, can I get the check mark now :-)